# Northwest vs Northwestern

Tags: differences, adjectives, geography

1. At its height, The Almohad Caliphate controlled much of the Iberian
   Peninsula and ***Northwest*** Africa.

or

2. At its height, The Almohad Caliphate controlled much of the Iberian
   Peninsula and ***Northwestern*** Africa.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You don't specify what your actual problem is, but there is no practical difference between the two except if one or the other has been specifically defined. See e.g. *[Why do we say "Eastern Europe" but "East Asia"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200557/why-do-we-say-eastern-europe-but-east-asia)* Also see *[Specifying geography with cardinal directions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185998)*